# using recursion to get controls from an aspx page that are within an html fieldset

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, recursion

I have a fieldset in my xaml that defines a load of label and text boxes. however. i cannot access the text boxes using recursion.

here is a snippet form the fieldset in my xaml:

```
<fieldset runat="server" id="fdst1" class="default_form">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerId" Text="Customer ID" runat="server" />
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged" ID="txtCustomerId"
                                Enabled="false" runat="server" />
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Associated Brand" runat="server" />
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged" ID="txtBrandName"
                                Enabled="false" runat="server" />
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
```

now here is the code I use to get the text box controls...

```
private List<DropDownList> GetDropDownLists()
        {
            List<DropDownList> controls = new List<DropDownList>();

            FindControls<DropDownList>(this.Controls, controls);

            return controls;
        }

/// <summary>
        /// this will find all the contols in a collection of a given type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of control to find</typeparam>
        /// <param name="Controls">Contol Collection to look through</param>
        /// <param name="foundControls">List of found controls</param>
        public static void FindControls<T>(ControlCollection Controls, List<T> foundControls) where T : class
        {
            T found = default(T);

            if (Controls != null && Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Controls[i] is T)
                    {
                        found = Controls[i] as T;
                        foundControls.Add(found);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        // Recursive method call.
                        FindControls<T>(Controls[i].Controls, foundControls);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the list that gets returned is empty, but I am passing in the pages. control collection in which the controls should be. This all works fine if i use tables but my boss insists it is in a fieldset. so my question is how do i get these text boxes out using recursion when using a fieldset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a fieldset in my xaml that defines a load of label and text
>   boxes.

This isn't XAML. That doesn't matter for purposes of this question, but it may hinder your search efforts. This is the markup portion of an ASP.Net server page or control.

```
List<DropDownList> controls = new List<DropDownList>();
FindControls<DropDownList>(this.Controls, controls);
```

The code you are using searches recursively for controls of a particular type. Your code is only looking for dropdown lists. I imagine something like this would work fine:

```
List<TextBox> controls = new List<TextBox>();
FindControls<TextBox>(this.Controls, controls);
```

> This all works fine if i use tables but my boss insists it is in a
>   fieldset. so my question is how do i get these text boxes out using
>   recursion when using a fieldset.

A `fieldset` is a much better container for form elements than a table. Custom recursion is necessary because ASP.Net does not recursively traverse controls by default. Placing the form elements inside a new container (i.e. the `fieldset`) adds a level to the hierarchy.